# cannot understand lambda expression output

Tags: c#, list, lambda, output

I have this code and do not understand why the out put is 22! I am afraid it should be 01! 
can anyone explain what happens? if the list store a method with a parameter, so the parameters should be 0 and 1 respectively!

```
List<Action> list = new List<Action>();

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    list.Add(() => Console.Write(i));
}

foreach (var it in list)
{
    it();
}
```

Comment: Closures capture *variables* not *values*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Closure ([1](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx), [2](http://geekswithblogs.net/rajeevr/archive/2012/02/26/closures-and-captured-variable.aspx)).

In your case `Console.Write(i)` will use value of `i` in the moment of action call. You firstly increment `i` in `for` loop then in second loop you call every action in the list. In the moment of call of every action `i` has value 2 - so, you get `22` as output.

To get expected result you should create local copy of `i` and use it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    var temp = i; 
    list.Add(() => Console.Write(temp));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Addition to Roma Doskoch's anwser, another approach is to avoid `for`.

```
var list = Enumerable
               .Range(0, 2)
               .Select<int, Action>(i => () => Console.Write(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

*Closures capture variables, not values.*

In your code, the closure captures the variable `i`, not whatever value happens to be stored in `i` on each iteration. When you invoke the action, the variable `i` has a value of `2` (because the loop has finished) and therefore `2` will be printed out twice.

In order to avoid this, as other answers already point out, you need to create a new variable every time around as a workaround to not being able to capture values; if you declare a new variable on every iteration then the result of capturing the variable is equivalent to capturing the value because you won't be changing it on the next iteration.